# Can we have 2 versions of bulk copy utility on the same server?

Tags: ssis, bcp

We have 2 SSIS packages.
One of the packages needs bcp version 12 and the other needs bcp version 15.
Can we have 2 versions of the bulk copy utility on the same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, BCP allows for multiple installations on a machine. For example, on my machine

```
C:\>cd "Program Files"

C:\Program Files>dir /s /b bcp.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe

C:\Program Files>cd "\Program Files (x86)"

C:\Program Files (x86)>dir /s /b bcp.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe
```

I can see that I have the 64 bit version of bcp that corresponds to 110 (SQL Server 2012), 130 (SQL Server 2016), and .. I have no idea what 170 is as 2019 is 150. Whatever, we can ask the utility itself what version it is and they report back that I have version 11, 14 and 15 installed

```
C:\Program Files (x86)>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe" -v
BCP - Bulk Copy Program for Microsoft SQL Server.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
Version: 15.0.2000.5

C:\Program Files (x86)>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe" -v
BCP - Bulk Copy Program for Microsoft SQL Server.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
Version: 14.0.3445.2

C:\Program Files (x86)>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe" -v
BCP - Bulk Copy Program for Microsoft SQL Server.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
Version: 11.0.2100.60
```

The only "trick" is to ensure when you invoke them that you provide the correct path otherwise, the first entry in the users PATH windows environment variable will take precedent.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes,** you can Bulk copy the data from one server to another instance server.
for more details for BCP utility.
follow this link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014